# How to display different text and links in html depending on the class that its embedded in

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to display different text and links depending on the category/class that the code is embedded in.
The following works in that it displays "Read more about Apples" or "Read more about Oranges" depending on the category/class that the code is embedded in. However I also want it to include different hyperlinks. I thought that the last two lines would do the job but the text doesn't appear with hyperlinks in it. Any ideas?

```
<style>
.category-apples themainbodya::after {
  content: " Apples";
}
.category-oranges themainbodyb::after {
  content: " Oranges";
}
</style>
<p>Read more about</p>
<themainbodya href=https://testa.test.com/ ></themainbodya>
<themainbodyb href=https://testo.test.com/ ></themainbodyb>
```

Comment: where are the tags with class `category-oranges` & `category-apples`?

Comment: This isn't specifically to do with the after element. What is the tag theainbodya? How is it defined? It doesn't seem to be following the rules for naming of a custom tag and href can only be put on certain elements. (most often the anchor, a, element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little worried that using pseudo elements that way could make the site a little less accessibility friendly as screen readers may not read out their content.

This snippet uses a slightly different method, the text 'apples', 'oranges' (and any other fruit) is put into the relevant element (as is an image just to show one way of it being done, though you may prefer to use background-image). Those elements are set to display: none initially, and then they display depending on which of the categories is set in the class list of the containing element.

As there are only two elements in the test, the toggle function is used to go between them, but of course for more elements you will want a bit more JS to remove the unwanted classes.

```css
*[class*="themainbody"] {
  display: none;
}

.category-apples .themainbodya {
  display: block;
}

.category-oranges .themainbodyb {
  display: block;
}

.container img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="const c = document.querySelector('.container'); c.classList.toggle('category-oranges'); c.classList.toggle('category-apples');">Toggle between oranges and apples</button>
<div class="container category-oranges">
  <p>Read more about</p>
  <a class=themainbodya href=https://testa.test.com/><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4FFq.jpg" alt="apple">Apples</a>
  <a class=themainbodyb href=https://testo.test.com><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsIvt.png" alt="orange">Oranges</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. This looks exactly what I want. I'm thinking that I can put this all into inline html by putting <style></style> around the top box and <script></script> around the bottom one. Is that right? It's not working.

Comment: The bottom box is HTML not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint from A Haworth I worked out the answer. HOWEVER I still can't work out how to add a different image depending on whether it's apples or oranges.

```
<style>
.category-apples .themainbodya::after {
  content: " Apples";
}
.category-oranges .themainbodyb::after {
  content: " Oranges";
}
</style>
<p>Read more about</p>
<a class=themainbodya href=https://testa.test.com/ ></a>
<a class=themainbodyb href=https://testo.test.com/ ></a>
```

Comment: While this works I'm a bit concerned that it isn't too accessibility friendly so have put up an alternative (and included images).

Answer (score 0):

The answer from A Haworth is excellent. I added to it to get a default too. I expect it can be optimised, so feel free to make further suggestions.

```
    <style>
    *[class*="themainbody"] {
        display: none;
      }
      
      *[class*="samsdefault"] {
        display: block;
    }
    
      .category-apples .themainbodya {
        display: block;
      }
    
      .category-apples .samsdefault {
        display: none;
    }
      
      .category-oranges .themainbodyb {
        display: block;
      }
    
      .category-oranges .samsdefault {
        display: none;
    }
    
      
      .container img {
        width: 100px;    
      }
    </style>
    <button onclick="const c = document.querySelector('.container'); c.classList.toggle('category-oranges'); c.classList.toggle('category-apples');">Toggle between oranges and apples</button>
    <div class="container category-oranges">
      <p>Read more about</p>
      <a class=themainbodya href=https://testa.test.com/><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4FFq.jpg" alt="apple">Apples</a>
      <a class=themainbodyb href=https://testo.test.com><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsIvt.png" alt="orange">Oranges</a>
      <a class=samsdefault href=https://testd.test.com /><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsIvt.png" alt="carrot"><br>Carrots</a>
    </div>
```